# Discontinuous automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Tags: continuity, field-theory

I'm trying to find an algebraic number $\alpha$ and a "discontinuous automorphism", in the analysis sense, of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. I've been toying around with conjugation of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and trying to show it's a discontinuous map using the usual $\epsilon-\delta$ argument but I've no idea how to properly manipulate the inequalities.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: The map is discontinuous at $\sqrt 2$: it gets thrown far away, but any rationals nearby stay fixed.